# Run C++ executable on Linux

Tags: c++, opencv, c++11, g++

I am trying to compile an execute a C++ program in Linux using OpenCV.

When I type

```
g++ -c facedetection.cpp -std=c++11 -o facedetection
```

The `facedetection` file is correctly generated. Please note that I use `-std=c++11` because I had an error advising to do so.

After doing `chmod o+x facedetection` I try to execute it with `./facedetection` but I get error:

```
bash: ./facedetection: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you compile with `-c`, it generates an object (`.o`) file, not an executable. You need to compile it without `-c` in order to make an executable file.

Larger C++ programs will have more than one `.cpp` file; for each `.cpp` file, you would compile using `-c` to generate their respective `.o` file. Then you would *link* these `.o` files (running `g++` without `-c`) to generate the final executable.